# Bootstrap Navbar Fixed Top sobrepondo o slider carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css3, menu

Estou fazendo um menu navbar fixed top e quero que este menu acompanhe o scroll quando desliza a página, porém a navbar está se sobrepondo a seção logo abaixo que é o slider. Queria saber como deixa-lo na posição sem sobrepor o slider bem como deslizar juntamente com o scroll.

O jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fhvo7anz/

Comment: O certo é que realmente toda navbar fixed permaneça no topo da página e acima de todos os elementos, mas você pode sobrepor a navbar com o próprio carrosel. Você pode definir propriedade de `position: absolute;` e talvez até um `z-index`.

Comment: Mas oque eu pretendo é, exemplificando: que o menu fique na posição sele, sem sobrepor o carrosel e vice e versa e quando deslizarmos a página este mesmo menu siga o deslizamento estando no topo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara, pra usar o Navbar-Fixed-Top precisamos atribuir um valor de **padding** pro elemento **body**, pois o Navbar no CSS fica como **"position: fixed"**, e com esse atributo, ele não tem influência nos outros elementos da tela, ou seja, não vai "empurrar" para baixo o conteúdo.

É só acrescentar isso no CSS

```
/*Para dispositivos com width menor que 768px*/
body {
  padding-top: 290px;
}

/*Para dispositivos com width maior ou igual a 768px*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 body {
     padding-top: 220px;
  }
}
```

Veja como ficou: https://jsfiddle.net/fhvo7anz/5/

Comment: mas quando aplicado em resoluções diferentes (fazendo aquele joguinho de aumentar e diminuir o browser) a diferença "fixa" permanece. Como alterar isto? por exemplo, dá um saque nesse site > http://shapebootstrap.net/demo/html/multi/ aumentando e diminuindo o slider se mantem "colado" ao menu.

Comment: Então, mais ou menos, né... Se você prestar atenção, ao deixar em um tamanho médio, uma parte do slider fica por trás do menu. Mas dá pra arrumar. É só você pegar os valores que o Bootstrap muda o layout responsivo e incluir com os tamanhos que cada resolução deixa o navbar.

Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/fhvo7anz/5/

Comment: Verdade, tava reparando isto. Valeu pela ajuda.